# Mail Server send spams

Tags: 12.04, postfix, mail-server

My mail server got black-listed on Barracuda for some reason, how to make sure if my mail server is sending spams or if some script on it is sending bulk mails/spamming ?

Comment: http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Detect_if_your_mailserver_is_used_as_a_spambot

Comment: thank you, What should the keyword (relay) refer to?, also i didn't get the meaning of the last command `cat /var/log/mail.info | grep -E "^.* .* .* .*: .*: to="`

Comment: If your mail server is configured as an open relay, and it is accessible from the external network, then it is almost certainly being used to route spam messages to the world.

Comment: I tested my mail server on "mxtoolbox", it doesn't have "open relay"